# Why does the ID and name in navigation need to add underscore _ in Android Studio?

Tags: android

The Code A1 is from the project CameraX sample at https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/res/navigation

I'm very strange why the ID and name in navigation need to add  underscore `_`

For sample

```
android:id="@+id/action_camera_to_gallery"

android:name="root_directory"
```

But in fact, these underscore `_`  are moved when invoked, maybe the automatically generated code do that, you can see Code A2. The two IDs between `action_camera_to_gallery` and `actionCameraToGallery` is not corresponding!

If I write code, I will use Code B1 and Code B2.

Why does the ID and name in navigation need to add  underscore `_` in Android Studio?

**Code A1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/permissions_fragment">

     ...

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/camera_fragment"
        android:name="com.android.example.cameraxbasic.fragments.CameraFragment"
        android:label="CameraFragment" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_camera_to_gallery"
            app:destination="@id/gallery_fragment" />


    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gallery_fragment"
        android:name="com.android.example.cameraxbasic.fragments.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="GalleryFragment" >

        <argument
            android:name="root_directory"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

**Code A2**

```
controls.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.photo_view_button).setOnClickListener {
   Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
           CameraFragmentDirections.actionCameraToGallery(outputDirectory.absolutePath))
}


val rootDirectory = File(args.rootDirectory)
```

**Code B1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/permissions_fragment">

     ...

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/camera_fragment"
        android:name="com.android.example.cameraxbasic.fragments.CameraFragment"
        android:label="CameraFragment" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionCameraToGallery"
            app:destination="@id/gallery_fragment" />


    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gallery_fragment"
        android:name="com.android.example.cameraxbasic.fragments.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="GalleryFragment" >

        <argument
            android:name="rootDirectory"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

**Code B2**

```
controls.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.photo_view_button).setOnClickListener {
   Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
           CameraFragmentDirections.actionCameraToGallery(outputDirectory.absolutePath))
}


val rootDirectory = File(args.rootDirectory)
```

Comment: What makes you think they _need_ to have underscores?

Comment: Thanks! I think maybe they make some problem, they make a simple thing into complex

Comment: They think that  `rootDirectory` is the same as `root_directory`, but It's hard to understand for a normal users.

Comment: I can't accept a automatically generated code to do the convert without any prompt!

Comment: I think you should look in general at conventions in both Android XML ids and Java/Kotlin code - snake case is indeed the standard for Android XML ids and camel case is indeed the standard for Java/Kotlin code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are equally valid - either `android:id="@+id/actionCameraToGallery"` (camel case) or `android:id="@+id/action_camera_to_gallery"` (snake case) will be converted into camel case for method names by Safe Args. This is intentional as per [the original issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79642240).

Comment: Thanks! but I can't get any prompt.

Comment: I think that ID can not be allowed to convert

Comment: What prompt are you looking for? When you apply the Safe Args Gradle Plugin, it automatically generates Safe Args for every navigation graph in your project. That includes converting everything to camel case.

Comment: And the convert is to do automatically by system. A normal use don't know that the system do that convert secretly.

Comment: Yes, all snake cases are converted to camel case. I've included a link to the issue in my answer where the conversion was added specifically because snake case is not the convention in Java / Kotlin method names.

Comment: Thanks! from the article https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args , I can't find the rule to convert ID based camel case

Comment: In my mind, ID is unique, and can't be changed on the same control

Comment: There's no 'changing' involved. The actual `R.id` is exactly where it was. Generated Java/Kotlin code is not beholden to being exactly the same - you'll note that argument names, class names, and every other piece of generated code follows the same convention that snake case should not appear anywhere in generated code methods or class names. The docs do specifically call out the class names conversion (from `main_nav` to `MainNavDirections`).